# Give back JSON Array with Sub-Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

My table looks like:

```
id | title | link | kind
------------------------
 1   link1   http   one
 4   link2   http   two
 2   link9   http   one
```

I want to give back a JSON Array (JSON parsing is not the problem!) which looks like:

```
one
 - link1, http
 - link9, http
two
 - link2, http
```

The kind-colum is **dynamic** so I do not know the actual string. (But it is never (null)!)

What I have:

```
$links = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $link = array(
        'title' => $row->title,
        'link' => $row->link,
        'kind' => $row->kind
    );
    $links[] = $link;
}

echo json_encode($links);
```

That's one array with all columns for each element.

Comment: Which is the question? I don't understand what do you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $row->kind as an index into the top level array.

```
$kinds = array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2, ...etc...);
$links = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $link = array(
        'title' => $row->title,
        'link' => $row->link
    );
    $links[$kinds[$row->kind]][] = $link;
}

echo json_encode($links);
```

Comment: Appending to an empty value is fine and will create a new array, at least up until PHP 5.3 (don't know about 5.4). It will not even give warnings with `E_ALL`.
Edit: I assume this is an intended feature since it simplifies code like this a lot.

Comment: OK, this works ... But i guess there's still an error. iPhone crashes. I need the structure: Array -> Array -> Dictionary

Comment: You can't have an outer dictionary with the keys being strings 'one', 'two', etc. Do you want to convert the literal numbers to integers?

Comment: I don't know if you're in Obj.-C. coding, but what I want to do is: `[[[myArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:y] valueForKey:@"title"]` to get each title-value.

Comment: Then you need to map the one, two etc. two integers instead. Add `$kinds = array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2, etc.`) at the top and instead of $links[$row->kind][] = $link` do `$links[$kinds[$row->kind]][] = $link`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in MySQL query:

```
SELECT CONCAT("[",
          GROUP_CONCAT(
               CONCAT("{".kind.":'",title ,"'"),
               CONCAT(",".kind.":'",link),"'}")
          )
     ,"]") AS json
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: what happens if title has quotes?